# WP7 Accessing phone files and folders

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

How to access the files and folders from the phones memory not application memory(i.e isolated storage) ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Every app has its own directory and permissions to operate inside it. There is no chance to get to files outside that directory.

You can use launchers and choosers to get some data from other places (like contact list or photos) but you cannot get to that files directly.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an option of loading a SQL database from the application install directory (not isolated storage). see http://blog.arsanth.com/index.php/2011/06/02/working-with-pre-populated-sql-ce-databases-in-wp7/ for details. This can be done using the connection string e.g. `datasource=’appdata:/db.sdf’; mode=’read only'`. You might be able to do something similar to read files from the Application Install directory.

Comment: i think even that db file is first generated in isolated storage. Access to other parts of phone memory is limited by Launchers and Choosers i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

there is something called IsolatedStorageExplorer -> http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/